# Can an OTF font, without relying on anything else, render complex TeX formula?

Tags: fonts, html

OTF fonts a have a number of [features](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/opentype-font-features) such as:

- Variants
- Ligatures
- Swashes
- Alternates
- etc.

Is it possible to use a combination of these features to render complex math formulae without depending on a particular environment or tool (e.g. MS Word, SVG, HTML canvas) but just an environment that supports all OTF features?

For example, the [Fira Code](https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode) font uses ligatures to render these semi-complex symbols in any environment that supports ligatures -- editors and IDEs, terminals, word processors, etc:

[image: Fira Code]

To be more specific, Fira Code renders `!=` as `≠` or `<->` as `↔`.

My question is, does OTF have everything that is needed to render more complex formulae (e.g. everything that can be rendered using MathJax or similar tools) just by relying on OTF features, and nothing else?

To be more precise, with almost every ordinary font (Arial, Courier, Times New Roman, etc.):

```
\f{x} = \int_{-\infty}^\infty
\hat \f\xi\,e^{2 \pi i \xi x}
\,d\xi
```

is rendered just as is. But can someone design a font *F* that when given

```
\f{x} = \int_{-\infty}^\infty
\hat \f\xi\,e^{2 \pi i \xi x}
\,d\xi
```

it renders it as:

[image: Font X]

?

Comment: How is this related to TeX?

Comment: What you show is a default math output which can be done with every oft math font,e.g. Stix2

Comment: @Johannes_B Unfortunately I couldn't find a more related stack exchange site.

Comment: @Johannes_B no! I am asking if OTF already has all the features needed to render complex math formulae using ligatures and other features and if so, if there are any fonts that use these OTF features to do that.

Comment: How are you going to “give” `\f{x} ...` to the font? That is not how fonts work.

Comment: Rendering math is quite different from, and far more complex than, rendering text. There is much much more to typesetting math than adding a few frills here and there to a text font. While there are thousands (and probably tens or even hundreds of thousands) otf text fonts out there, I'd be surprised if more than a dozen or so high-quality otf math fonts exist. To start getting an appreciation for how rendering math is far more complex than rendering text is, please read the entire user guide of the [unicode-math](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/unicode-math?lang=en) package.

Comment: I'm afraid this is off-topic for us. I think you need to work out what you really mean by the 'font doing it'. The font itself doesn't really do anything: it's data structures are used by the shaper which loads it. You seem to be suggesting that a font should be a self-contained typesetting system, which would require them to be very large, repetitive (and probably buggy), etc.

Comment: OTF supports ligatures. An OTF rendering engine can render an "f" followed by an "i" elegantly using ligatures (by joining f & i and removing the dot on top of i). Some fonts have extended their support for ligatures to render a larger sequence of characters in a specific form. So an OTF rendering engine, using a specialized font, can render specific sequences of letters in different shapes & forms (e.g. see Fira Code). I am asking if an OTF rendering engine, using a specially crafted font, can render even more complex shapes such as math formulas?